# Merge duplicate row using unique column

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to do a per subject and I'm trying to achieve 2 things.

1. It ran successful until it got 'Run-time error 13 Type mismatch'. However when I stop the code, it manage to churn out the data successful. Am I right to say that this error occurs due to blank rows?

[image: Code as follow]

2. Instead of using Column A as the unique column, I want to use column K as the unique column. However when I uses 'sh2.Range("K:K")' on line 11, I will get 'Run-time error 1004 You can't past this here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size'. What I'm trying to achieve is using column K as the unique column and copy paste the entire sheet, after merging the duplicate, as it is but failed.

Any advice is appreciated.

Putting the source code here for anyone helping to work on.

```
Sub Merge_Duplicate()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, f As Range, g As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sh1 = Worksheets(2)
    Set sh2 = Worksheets(3)

    sh2.Cells.ClearContents
    sh1.Rows(1).Copy sh2.Rows(1)

    For i = 2 To sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To sh1.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If sh1.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                Set f = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(sh1.Cells(i, "A"), , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    Set g = sh2.Rows(1).Find(sh1.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole)
                    If Not g Is Nothing Then
                        sh2.Cells(f.Row, g.Column) = sh1.Cells(i, j)
                    End If
                Else
                    sh1.Rows(i).Copy sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What does "as the unique column" mean for you?

Comment: What's in that cell when it errors? You can't paste a whole column into anything but a range starting in row 1.

Comment: meaning instead of column A i want to use column K as the identifier to look for duplicate row @FaneDuru

Comment: basically when the error happens, nothing happens but when i stop the macro, the duplicate are churn out on another sheet @SJR

Comment: Are any cells `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Run-time error 13 Type mismatch` with `sh1.Cells(i, j) <> ""` if that cell is in error for example `#N/A`. Skip those with a check`IsError(sh1.Cells(i, j))` first.

```vb
Sub Merge_Duplicate1()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, f As Range, g As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sh1 = Worksheets(2)
    Set sh2 = Worksheets(3)

    sh2.Cells.ClearContents
    sh1.Rows(1).Copy sh2.Rows(1)

    For i = 2 To sh1.Range("K" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set f = sh2.Range("K:K").Find(sh1.Cells(i, "K"), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To sh1.Cells(i, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If IsError(sh1.Cells(i, j)) Then
                    ' do nothing
                ElseIf sh1.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                    sh2.Cells(f.Row, j) = sh1.Cells(i, j)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            sh1.Rows(i).Copy sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Range("K" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: sadly this only churn out only 1 row instead of the entire data. I've tried replacing your code `sh1.Rows(i).Copy sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)` with `sh1.Rows(i).Copy sh2.Range("K" & sh2.Range("K" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)` but I got `'Run-time error 1004 You can't past this here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size'`. I'm trying to use column K as the identifier column for duplicates and copy paste the entire sheet though but unsuccessful

Comment: @Kaiju When you copy a row (which is all 16,384 columns) you have to paste it into column A. If you paste to K you only have room for 16,374 columns (that is what the error message is telling you). I'm guessing if you have data on sheet 1 in columns A:E you want to paste those rows into K:O on sheet P. So unique ID is in column A on sheet 1 and column K on sheet 2. Is that correct?

Comment: Lemme try to rephrase it. On sheet2 I have column A:Z and i want to copy paste to sheet3 all the columns as it is A:Z while removing the duplicate rows using Column K as the reference/unique column. I hope that make sense to you. @CDP1802

Comment: @kailju Can you post a screen shot of worksheet(2) please

Comment: I've added screenshot sample for your kind assistance @CDP1802

Comment: @kaiju I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you! you're a genius! @CDP1802